# Comparing Dates List with MAX Date

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have an output $a and $b with MAX date as shown below: I would like to compare both $a and $b which contains dates and get the results. The $a and $b will change on a daily basis. The goal is to get everything after the MAX Date everyday. The MAX date changes daily as new data is loaded with date and $a changes daily to.

This is how $a is derived:

```
$access_token ="Access_Token"

$URI =  "https://XXXXX"
$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $access_token”} 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers -ContentType $ContentType |ConvertTo-Json
$a = $Result|ConvertFrom-Json| Select -ExpandProperty Forms
```

```
$a= 

id          date
--------    -----------
Person 1    01/02/2017 10:59:15
Person 2    02/03/2017 13:10:19
Person 3    04/05/2017 11:11:12
Person 4    10/10/2017 10:42:19
Person 5    10/10/2017 13:34:58
```

```
$b= 

MAX_Date
02/03/2017 13:10:19
```

```
Desired results:

id          date
--------    -----------
Person 3    04/05/2017 11:11:12
Person 4    10/10/2017 10:42:19
Person 5    10/10/2017 13:34:58
```

Comment: What is `$a` and `$b`? Are they strings? Arrays of strings? Please show us how you created them in the first place

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen. They are Array of Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mathias said, we need more details. But to give you a head start the following would work:

```
$A = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        id   = 'Person 1'
        date = [DateTime]'01/02/2017 10:59:15'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        id   = 'Person 2'
        date = [DateTime]'02/03/2017 13:10:19'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        id   = 'Person 3'
        date = [DateTime]'04/05/2017 11:11:12'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        id   = 'Person 4'
        date = [DateTime]'10/10/2017 10:42:19'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        id   = 'Person 5'
        date = [DateTime]'10/10/2017 13:34:58'
    }
)

$B = @{
    MAX_Date = [DateTime]'02/03/2017 13:10:19 '
}

$A | Where-Object { $_.date -gt $B.MAX_Date } | Sort-Object id
```

Comment: The $a and $b will change on a daily basis. I there a way to do this without hard coding the dates in.

Comment: As Mathias said, we need more details. Where is the data coming from? What format is? What 's the goal?.... It's hard to answer a question without knowing all the details.

Comment: I have added how I got $a

Comment: @Djbril All you need is the last line.  How is this not the answer?

Comment: @js2010 I don't want the last line please look at the desired result. I want everything after $b which is 02/03/2017 13:10:19. I would have used Select-Object -Last 1 if I required the last line.

Comment: @Djbril, JS means all you need is the last line of code in this answer. It will yield the wanted results **if** `$b` is an object with property `MAX_Date`.

Comment: The data in $a changes on a daily basis so I need something so I don't need to hard code in the dates.

Comment: @Djbril, he only hard-coded dates to recreate your scenario. You can ignore everything above the last line if you already have `$a` and `$b`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings. Thats the bit I can't figure out. I appreciate your input on this.

Comment: @Djbril, if we assume you have `$a` and `$b` already and you **just run** `$A | Where-Object { $_.date -gt $B.MAX_Date } | Sort-Object id`, do you get the desired results?

Comment: @AdminOfThings. Thank You so much. It worked not sure I couldn't figure it out myself

Answer (score 0):

```
#First we need to cast this string into a date so it will compare properly.
$Max_Date = Get-Date $b.MAX_Date
#Then we need an array to store the objects that we want to keep
$Dates_to_Keep = ()
#Now we can iterate through the array and check the date on each object.
Foreach ($person in $a){
    #Again, casting this string as a date for accurate comparison. 
    $date = Get-Date $person.date
    If ($date -ge $Max_Date){
         $Dates_to_Keep = $Dates_to_Keep + $person
    }
}
Write-Host $Dates_to_Keep
```

This is my best guess based on the information provided in the OP.

Comment: This only picks up Person 5. I need it to pickup Person 3,4 as well as 5.

Comment: @Djbril let me know if that issue is still occuring. If so, I'm guessing that your $a is not a true array.